# Barrier class with divide and conquer (mutex destroyed while busy) C++

Tags: multithreading, c++11, barrier

I've tried implementing a barrier class. I want to test this using the divide and conquer algorithm. My class is defined as follows:

```
class barrier{
private:
    mutex mtx;
    condition_variable cv;
    atomic<int> counter;
    atomic<int> waiting;
    atomic<int> thread_count;

public:
    barrier(int count) : thread_count(count), counter(0), waiting(0) {}

    void wait()
    {
        //fence mechanism
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);
        ++counter;
        ++waiting;
        cv.wait(lock, [&] {return counter >= thread_count; });
        --waiting;
        if (waiting == 0) counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < thread_count; ++i) cv.notify_one();
        lock.unlock();
    }
};
```

As to the divide and conquer algorithm, I've implemented it as follows:

```
int main() {
    vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 };
    int n = size(v)/2;

    while (n >= 1) {
        dnc_light(v, n);
        n /= 2;
    }

    return 0;
}

void dnc_light (vector<int> &v, int n) {
    thread trd[50];
    barrier bar(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        trd[i] = thread([&] {
            v[i] += v[i + n];
            bar.wait();
        });
    }
}
```

This however results in a "mutex destroyed while busy" - error. How come? I need to handle the size of `barrier bar(...)` dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This however results in a "mutex destroyed while busy" - error. How come?

`dnc_light` creates multiple threads with a reference to local `barrier` object. Then the function returns destroying that local `barrier` those threads still use, which causes "mutex destroyed while busy" error.

Also, the threads are joinable, so that their destructors are going to throw an exception because they are neither joined nor detached.

A fix would be to join the threads before returning from the function:

```
void dnc_light(vector<int> &v, int n) {
    vector<thread> trd(n);
    barrier bar(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        trd[i] = thread([&](){
            v[i] += v[i + n];
            bar.wait();
        });
    }

    for(auto& t : trd)
        t.join();
}
```

In the above code you do not need the barrier at all because this join loop waits till all threads terminate anyway.

---

The variables in `barrier` do not need to be atomic because it only accesses them while holding the mutex. Simplification:

```
class barrier {
    mutex mtx;
    condition_variable cv;
    int const thread_count;
    int counter{0};
    int waiting{0};

public:
    barrier(int count) : thread_count(count) {}

    void wait() {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);
        ++counter;
        ++waiting;
        cv.wait(lock, [&](){
            return counter >= thread_count;
        });
        if(waiting == thread_count)
            cv.notify_all();
        if(!--waiting)
            counter = 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: I have just tested it and your suggestions work. I have two questions: Could I just detach the threads in `dnc_light` instead of joining them? Yesterday I tried coding everything in the main function this however resulted in the same error - is that because the barrier was destroyed after the for-loop?

Comment: @SAFD You can detach threads to avoid having to join them. In that case, however, you must make sure the barrier stays alive. One way to do that is to `auto barrier = make_shared<barrier>(n);` and pass `barrier` smart pointer by value to the threads, so that it stays alive while in use.

Comment: Okay, that is too complex for me I'm afraid. 
After some further testing I noticed, that the sum is not always 136. Sometimes the threads mess up the calculations. 
Therefore I changed `dnc_light`: now it catches `v` byval and has a vector `temp` onto which the sums are saved. This solved the issue to some extend. The only error I get now, is that some random sums end up being `0` - not always, though.

Comment: @SAFD That may be happening because multiple threads modify the same vector at the same time, which is a race condition.